# Restricted Scopes OAuth verification

Tags: google-contacts-api

I have received a mail from noreply-apps-developer@google.com with the subject “[Action Required] Submit your app(s) for Restricted Scopes OAuth verification”. In the email body, there is a link to the Google API Console. After I am in the Google API Console, under the tab named “Credentials” 2 fields are highlighted.
Following is the screenshot of the same.

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUNXr.png)

I would like to know the reason for the error “Invalid domain”. Also, would be great if you can help me resolve the issue.

Please note: In the sections highlighted in red color, the site URL is present. I have removed it from the screenshot for security concerns.

Edit1:

As suggested, I have added the links for privacy policy, domain, etc. When I click on the "Submit for verification" button, a modal appears. I am unable to identify what information I need to add here. The details are as follows:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f55BS.png) for the screenshot of the modal which appears when I click on the submit button.
The application interacts with gmail in 2 instances: 
 1. Sending emails.
 2. Reading emails received (emails having a particular subject line) and accessing the attachments present in it.

There is not other use of the gmail connectivity.
I am confused whether I should mark the application as "Internal" or should I submit it for verification. If I have to submit it for verification, then what details should I insert in the modal that appears on click of the "submit for verification" button (screenshot has been shared).
Request you to help me resolve the issue.

Comment: If you aren't familiar with Restricted Scopes, you may want to read more about what's involved with this new requirement. Using Gmail's APIs is now subject to a pretty intensive review in some cases. Nylas put together a nice [summary of the changes here](https://www.nylas.com/blog/google-oauth-updates-2019-timeline-and-everything-else-you-need-to-know). And Google's [FAQ on the subject](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#restricted-scopes) has the most up-to-date details.

Comment: Your description of your app makes it sound like it is best described as an "Email Client" (or perhaps "Email Productivity"). Why would you not choose one of those options?
And as for details, let Google know how you are using the Gmail APIs and give them some context about your application and why your users will want to allow it to send and receive their emails.

Answer (score 0):

All URLs in your project must match one of your **Authorized Domains**. But your screenshot shows this field to be blank. You will need to tell Google which domains your app is allowed to run on.

For example, let's assume your homepage is at `https://www.example.com/` and your privacy policy is at `https://www.example.com/privacy`. You'll need to include `example.com` in the first field under **Authorized Domains**.

In this screenshot below, I've added a matching Authorized Domain and the errors are resolved.

[image: sample Google OAuth consent setting for authorized domains]

Comment: Thanks a lot Graeme. A small doubt: Is it compulsory to add a privacy policy page link?

Comment: Yes, the privacy policy link is required when you submit for verification.

Comment: Thanks again, Graeme. 
Is there a way wherein I can simply mark the application as internal?
I checked the page, of which I have shared the initial screenshot, but it does not include the "internal" option.

Comment: I am trying to set the application type as internal using the link https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#mark-internal.
But I am unable to view the option "Application type". Please note: I do not want to add the organization and associate the project to it.

Comment: You can only make the app "internal" if there is an organization. Google's description of the internal application type says: "Only users with a Google Account in your organization can grant access to the scopes requested by this app."

Answer (score 0):

Check the "[Learn more](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en_US#authorized-domains)". It was stated in bold text that:

> **Add your Authorized Domains before you add your redirect or origin URIs, your homepage URL, your terms of service URL, or your privacy
>   policy URL.**

Looking into your screenshot, something is missing and it is your Authorized domains.